# Django Migration Error in Heroku, but migrate correctly in heroku local

Tags: python, django, heroku

Python 3.5, Django 1.10.3, Sqlite
I have deployed a django app in heroku.It ran correctly before. One day I make some change in `models.py`. I first do

```
python manage.py collectstatic  
python manage.py makemigrations  
python manage.py migrate
heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
```

,
 the app run correctly in local. Then I push my code to heroku.
I ran:

```
git push heroku master
heroku run bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

But server returned:

```
ProgrammingError at /twitter/blog/
column twitter_article.enable_comments does not exist
LINE 1: ...article"."content", "twitter_article"."pub_date", "twitter_a...
                                                         ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://super-pershing.herokuapp.com/twitter/blog/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
column twitter_article.enable_comments does not exist
LINE 1: ...article"."content", "twitter_article"."pub_date", "twitter_a...
                                                         ^
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python35.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.5.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg']
Server time:    Sat, 3 Dec 2016 11:03:58 +0800

Error during template rendering

In template /app/twitter/templates/twitter/blog.html, error at line 7
column twitter_article.enable_comments does not exist LINE 1: ...article"."content", "twitter_article"."pub_date", "twitter_a... ^
1   {% extends 'twitter/base.html' %}
2   {% load bootstrap3 %}
3   
4   {% block bootstrap3_content %}
5   {{ block.super }}
6   <div class="container">
7     {% if article_list %}
8       <ul>
9       {% for article in article_list %}
10        <li>
11          <h3><a href="/twitter/blog/{{ article.id }}/">{{ article.title }}</a></h3>
12        </li>
13      {% endfor %}
14      </ul>
15    {% else %}
16      <h3><strong>No Blog here</strong></h3>
17    {% endif %}
```

Here is my key model:

```
    from django.db import models
    from fluent_comments.moderation import moderate_model,comments_are_open, comments_are_moderated
    from fluent_comments.models import get_comments_for_model, CommentsRelation

    class Article(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
    content = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("pub_date")
    enable_comments = models.BooleanField("Enable comments", default=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    # Optional, give direct access to moderation info via the model:
    comments = property(get_comments_for_model)
    comments_are_open = property(comments_are_open)
    comments_are_moderated = property(comments_are_moderated)

    # Give the generic app support for moderation by django-fluent-comments:
    moderate_model(Article,
        publication_date_field='pub_date',
        enable_comments_field='enable_comments',
    )
```

If I drop my database and build a new database. Server won't report error. Why?
I'm using sqlite.
It is my first question in stackoverflow.com, and English is not my tongue. If there is some wrong in my word ,please forgive me and give me some advice.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback so we can work out what maybe causing the issue.

Comment: @Emett Speer  Thank you for your help. I have push the full traceback. It is enough?

Comment: Did you check in all of your migration files?

Comment: You **must not** run makemigrations on Heroku. Run it locally and **commit** the result, then run migrate only.

Comment: I would suggest what Daniel Roseman is saying. Let us know if that fixes the problem at all.

Comment: Should I push folder migrations to heroku? I never do that before.

Comment: I have try the idea what Daniel Roseman is saying. But It seems return errors the same as before. This time I add folder migrations to heroku. Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` in local and run `python manage.py migrate --fake` in heroku bash.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem and spent a lot of time to solve, so:
problem with CLI of Heroku and to need use bash:

```
heroku run bash
./manage.py makimigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

and all work succhess!